# GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow

Tags: java, google-oauth

After making a call to:

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES).setDataStoreFactory(
        dataStoreFactory).build();
Credential cred = flow.loadCredential(userIdFromMyApplication);
```

And finding our `userIdFromMyApplication` has not yet given us permission to use their Google account (i.e. `cred` is null) I do the following:

```
if (cred == null) {
  String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setState("/linkaccount")
     .setRedirectUri("http://myapp.com/oauth2.php").build();
  //redirect them to the url    
}
```

My question is, once they've granted my app access and my app's oauth2 redirect url I setup under my API access token is called by Google with the access `code` parameter set, how do I then associate this `code` with `userIdFromMyApplication` ?  Would I have to set `userIdFromMyApplication` within my call to `setState` when building the redirectUrl?  Is that a viable convention?  Or is there a more clever way to figure out what access token belongs to which user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either store the user ID in your httpSession, or add the user ID (ideally obfuscated) to the "state" parameter, which will then get included in the oauth callback. Personally I use httpSession.

Actually, the second method might pose a security risk, so go with the httpSession.

Comment: Ok, I was going to have the callback operating under a different container (i.e. one central Oauth2 callback handler), however I'll forgo that if the convention is typically to have it running in the same session as the request.  Thanks @pinoyyid

Comment: You could probably use the state parameter to pass an obfuscated user id. Just make sure you've thought through any security implications.

Comment: now that I think about it more, I'm going to have to add something to the state param in order to retrieve the uid out of the session anyway right? My scenario is `[javascript in browser]==POST==>[My Server]==GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow==>[Google's Server]==Callback with code==>[My Server]`  That all won't happen within the same httpsession will it?

Comment: Oh wait... Really it's the client's browser who's making the call to the callback... so It's the same session.  Thanks!